# Epson Printer Driver

Tags: printing, ubuntu-drivers

I want to download and install a driver for an ET-2750 Epson printer. The instructions indicate I need to download and install lsb first. When I try, I get this response;
Reading state information... Done
Package lsb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lsb' has no installation candidate.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install -f`! Then try again...

Comment: I tried what you suggested and saw a number of messages ending with;

Comment: Here are just a few of the messages I got from sudo apt install -f ending with   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic snap-confine ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: I'm really not used to a comments section that posts a comment every time I hit the return key. I tried running the lsb command and I still get the same response. sudo apt-get install lsb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package lsb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lsb' has no installation candidate. I do appreciate the help but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Enable universe repo with command `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, then `sudo apt update` and finally `sudo apt install lsb` and let me know hoe it goes!

Comment: George Udosen-Thank you for your suggestion but I'm afraid I get exactly the same message when I run sudo apt install lsb. Do you know of another resource for Epson printer drivers? Perhaps there is a generic driver that might work for a range of Epson printers.

Comment: Please run `grep -R universe /etc/apt/sources*` and add the result to your question!

Comment: George - Thanks for paying attention to this and trying to help. The entire response is too long to fit in a single comment section. I'll have to do multiple.  grep -R universe /etc/apt/sources*
/etc/apt/sources.list:## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe

Comment: Please kindly add it to your question!

Comment: I did multiple comments. What you see above is the entire response from grep -R universe/etc/apt/sources. I had to split it into four separate sections.

Comment: George-I do appreciate having taken the time to try to answer my questions about the Epson printer driver. Do you know if there is a generic printer driver that might work? I have tried installing a couple of different drivers, to no avail. I'm getting to a place where I need to print some things and the deal for buying the Epson was that I would get $30.00 off if I turned in my old printer so I don't have a back-up printer right now. I did scope out if there was a printer driver for this printer before I bought it and finding one, I felt safe. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: George - if you're still looking at this, I found some information about installing lsb. It now appears the command worked. Next, I did what was suggested and here's what I got;craig@vesalius:~$ sudo dpkg -i imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.3.38.x86.deb
dpkg-split: error: error reading imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.3.38.x86.deb: Is a directory
dpkg: error processing archive imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.3.38.x86.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.3.38.x86.deb